# How to add color to DataTable row in VB.net base on condition

Tags: c#, vb.net, datatable, colors

I want to fill the Datatable row with color instead of a string. The color is a representation of the string value. I have tried Color and Brushes as you can see in the code below. How can I make this happen?

For instance, On the frontend, I want users to see color GREEN if cib = "EXIST/ACTIVE"

if cib = "EXIST/ACTIVE" display Yellow.

These values are coming from the Database

[image: colorrep]

```
hdfAccountNumber.Value = GenericManager.decryptQueryString(Request.QueryString("AccountNumber"))
        Dim CustomerChannels = GetCustomerDetails(hdfAccountNumber.Value)
        Dim ussd As String = CustomerChannels.USSD + "/" + CustomerChannels.USSDStatus
        Dim cib As String = CustomerChannels.CIB + "/" + CustomerChannels.BBGStatus
        Dim rib As String = CustomerChannels.RIB + "/" + CustomerChannels.RIBStatus
        Dim mobile As String = CustomerChannels.MOBILEBANKING + "/" + CustomerChannels.NEWMOBILEStatus
        Dim debitCard As String = CustomerChannels.CardStatus

        Dim ussdColor As Color
        Dim cibColor As Color
        Dim ribColor As Color
        Dim mobileColor As Color
        Dim debitCardColor As Color



        Dim ChannelTable As New DataTable
        ChannelTable.Columns.Add("USSD")
        ChannelTable.Columns.Add("CIB")
        ChannelTable.Columns.Add("RIB")
        ChannelTable.Columns.Add("MOBILE")
        ChannelTable.Columns.Add("DEBIT CARD")

        For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DataGrid1.Rows
            cib = row.Cells(1).Value
            If cib = "EXIST/ACTIVE" Then
                cibColor = Color.Green
                row.DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = cibColor
            ElseIf cib = "EXIST/INACTIVE" Then
                cibColor = Color.Yellow
                row.DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = cibColor
            Else
                cibColor = Color.Red
                row.DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = cibColor
            End If

            ussd = row.Cells(0).Value
            If ussd = "EXIST/ACTIVE" Then
                ussdColor = Color.Green
                row.DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = ussdColor
            ElseIf ussd = "EXIST/INACTIVE" Then
                ussdColor = Color.Yellow
                row.DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = ussdColor
            Else
                ussdColor = Color.Red
                row.DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = ussdColor
            End If

        Next

        ChannelTable.Rows.Add(ussdColor, cibColor, rib, mobile, debitCard)
        DataGrid1.DataSource = ChannelTable
        DataGrid1.DataBind()
    End Sub
```

datagrid

```
   <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel4" runat="server" class=""  style="color:#ffffff; margin-top: 5px; font-size: 12px">
             <ContentTemplate>
       <p  style="font-weight: 700; font-weight: 700; margin-left: 10px; font-weight: normal; font-size: 14px;">Channels<span> <asp:Button ID="availableChannel" runat="server" Text="Get channels"  CssClass="tdcolor" /> </span></p>
          <asp:DataGrid ID="DataGrid1" runat="server" style="width: 100%; margin-top: -8px; font-weight: 600; border: 1px solid #5c2684;">  
          </asp:DataGrid>         
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: I want to display "Green" to the user if cib = "EXIST/ACTIVE" and so on

Comment: you want to change row color or cell color?

Comment: I want to change Cell color

Comment: A DataTable does not have a .Color property or a .Cell property. It is an in memory representation of a table. You can have a column in the DataTable the contains a color you want to display.

Comment: .ForeColor in the color of the text that would be displayed in the cell. .BackColor is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

try below code. You need to use the attributes of row.DefaultCellStyle.* to set row color and other formatting

```
 For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DataGrid1.Rows
    cib = row.Cells(1).value 
    If cib = "EXIST/ACTIVE" Then
        cibColor = Brushes.Green
        row.DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = cibColor
    ElseIf cib = "EXIST/INACTIVE" Then
        cibColor = Brushes.Yellow
        row.DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = cibColor
    Else
        cibColor = Brushes.Red
        row.DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = cibColor
    End If

    ussd = row.Cells(0).value 
    If ussd = "EXIST/ACTIVE" Then
        ussdColor = Color.Green
        row.DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = ussdColor
    ElseIf ussd = "EXIST/INACTIVE" Then
        ussdColor = Color.Yellow
        row.DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = ussdColor
    Else
        ussdColor = Color.Red
        row.DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = ussdColor
    End If
```

Comment: I am getting ```Expression is of type 'DataGrid', which is not a collection type```

Comment: try now, in case of error, please copy-paste the stacktrace...itll be helpful

Comment: StackTrace ```Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error BC30456 'Rows' is not a member of 'DataGrid'. Infopool```

Comment: what is the data type of DataGrid1? Seems like it is not a GridView Control

Comment: its just DataGrid

Comment: I have updated my question with the complete view

Comment: use GridView instead of DataGrid, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/05yye6k9(v=vs.100)?redirectedfrom=MSDN

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231575/discussion-between-zeeshan-arif-and-techstack).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `nameof` to get the string name of the color.

```
var colorName = nameof(Brushes.Green);
```

Comment: I mean the color its self not the string name